# Printing InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, domdocument

Can someone tell me why 'printArea' in Javascript is comming up as undefined.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="text/javascript">
    function printArea(areaName)
    {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(areaName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="printThis">
  Hello I am a printable area
 </div>
 <input type="button" onclick="printArea('printThis');" Value="Print">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/cFeNp/

Comment: Your jsfiddle is wrong, it is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cFeNp/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `language="text/javascript"` with  `type="text/javascript"`

Answer (score 1):

You javascript declaration is not right. Must be:

> `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 1):

If u want to get HTML of printThis Div,Here is the java script code for the same

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printArea(areaName)
{
   var html =  document.getElementById('printThis').innerHTML; alert(html);
} 
</script>
```